# Как в данном случае будет выглядеть линейная схема предложения?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

«Десять грузчиков с неимоверным трудом поворачивали рулон весом в полтонны, и, когда работа была наконец-то завершена, собравшиеся увидели: перед ними ни что иное, как "Принцесса Грёза", которая и сейчас взирает на москвичей со стены гостиницы "Метрополь"»

Как показать слово "наконец-то" между двух частей составного именного сказуемого? Что делать с "ни чем иным, как" вообще не представляю...

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*Десять грузчиков с неимоверным трудом поворачивали рулон весом в полтонны, и, когда работа была **наконец-то** завершена, собравшиеся увидели: перед ними **не что иное,** как "Принцесса Грёза", которая и сейчас взирает на москвичей со стены гостиницы "Метрополь".*

**Пояснение**

1. *Была завершена **наконец-то*** — в предложении **инверсия** наречия.
2. Перед ними (что?). ***Не что иное как*** — особый речевой оборот, построенный по образцу противопоставления НЕ...А.

[Розенталь § 43. Местоименные сочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=54#pp54)